# Changing a variable in .XLSM files using Python, Run Macro and Save it into another file

Tags: python-3.x, excel, cell

I am not sure how to develop a functional code. I am using a free macro-enabled software found online and tried to automate this. I found several codes but I still cannot run this properly/the python cannot read the code.

```
data_location=".xlsm" 
output_location=".xlsm"
ori_wb=openpyxl.load_workbook(data_location, keep_vba=True) 
ori_sh=ori_wb['Input'] 
ori_sh[range(E6)]='30'                            #Changing (e6) value to 30 for example 
run.ori_sh 
ori_wb.save(output_location) 
new_wb=openpyxl.load_workbook(output_location, data_only=True) 
new_sh=new_wb.get_sheet_by_name('Input') 
print(new_sh)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJr8d.png)

Comment: Are you trying to run the code behind the Start button?

Comment: Yes I want to run the Start button(it calculates a lot a lot of equation). I want to automate this using python by varying temperature. I found the excel file (hydrogeosieveXL) online at http://www.people.ku.edu/~jfdevlin/Software.html